# label does not behave properly

Tags: c#, asp.net, label

I am devleoping a online airline reservation system    in which i have two dropdownlists to select source and destinations  and a label .this label will show " there are  no flights" if there are no matching routes  retrieved from the database (in this case  its sqlserver 2008).i have written the following code   which tries to do so, but when i postback or refresh the page the label with  " there are  no flights"  is till visible.what is wrong with my code  please anyone help me with that.

```
public partial class Dropdndemo : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection("Data Source=KUNDAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ars2.1.2;Integrated Security=True");
        //string Sqlcmnd="select Source from Ars2.1.2.dbo.Scheduling";
       con.Open();
       if (!Page.IsPostBack)
       {
           SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("select distinct Source from Schedulings", con);
           SqlCommand comn=new SqlCommand("select distinct Destination from Schedulings", con);
           //SqlDataReader readr;
           DropDownList1.DataSource = com.ExecuteReader();

           DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Source";
           // DropDownList1.DataTextField = "Destination";
           DropDownList1.DataBind();
           DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "select Source");
           con.Close();
           con.Open();


           DropDownList2.DataSource = comn.ExecuteReader();
           DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Destination";
           DropDownList2.DataBind();
           DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "select Destination");
           con.Close();


       }
        //con.Close();
       // DropDownList1.DataBind();
        //con.Close();
        if (IsPostBack)
           Label3.Text = "";
       //Label1.Visible = false;



    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // string Source = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();
       // Label1.Text = Source;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


            string src = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string desti = DropDownList2.SelectedItem.ToString();

            if ((src == desti) && IsPostBack)
            {


                Label1.Text = "Source And Destination cant be same!";


            }

            SqlConnection lop = new SqlConnection("Data Source=KUNDAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Ars2.1.2;Integrated Security=True");

            lop.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Schedulings where Source=@Source and Destination=@Destination", lop);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Source", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Destination", DropDownList2.SelectedItem.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                Label3.Text = "No planes available in this route!!!";

            }



    }
    protected void DropDownList2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: How is Label3 defined in the markup file?

Comment: the mark up iss given below:
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" ></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
    
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are refreshing page using <kbd>F5</kbd> or by right clicking on page and opting refresh option or using refresh button of browser. If this is the case then I am scared it's not refresh, it's repeating previous action. That means if you were searching for flight and refreshing using above options, it will again search for flight using same search criteria. You can confirm it by putting debugger on search event. You can avoid this behavior by setting and clearing Session or ViewState and manage label text using it.

Comment: can you please help me  how to put a debugger on search event.?

Comment: Put your mouse on click event and hit F9 button

Comment: i have tried what you have suggested but till now the problem is not resolved

Comment: Used session or view state?

Comment: i have used view state but it creates more problems by giving null object reference exception ........in which way the session is to be used?can you provide some example